# Python nested for-loop to numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

learning python 3.X as a hobby. I wrote a simple pixelsearch:

```
        im = Image.open("photo.jpg").convert('RGB').Load
        for x1, y1 in product(range(300, 1100, 1), range(200, 500, 1)):
            r,g,b =im[x1,y1]
            rx,gx,bx = 200, 20, 20
            if abs(rx - r)<=5 and abs(gx - g)<=5 and abs(bx - b)<=5:
                do stuff
                break
```

I want it to perform in real-time to detect a specific color on screen. But its a bit slow for that. 
I tried to replace the iteretools.product with numpy.

```
        for y in np.arange(200,500,1):
            for x in np.arange(300,1100,1):
                r,g,b =im[x1,y1]
```

but it gives an error: "Typeerror: an Integer is required." 
What am I doing wrong? and is my method the right way to convert to numpy to improve performance?

Comment: First of all, `x1` and `y1` are not defined in your second part as you renamed the loop variables to `x` and `y`. Second you still have loops. To increase the performance you should get rid of these and replace them with vectorized operations. Otherwise the performance won't get better. To help you, though, one would need to know what "do stuff" is.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the mask of matches in a vectorized fashion as a `pre-processing` step, like so -

```
mask = (np.abs(im[300:1100, 200:500] - [200,20,20]) <= 5).all(-1)
```

Then, use this mask when looping -

```
for yi,y in enumerate(np.arange(200,500,1)):
    for xi,x in enumerate(np.arange(300,1100,1)):
        if mask[xi,yi]:
            #do something
```

So, the idea is to minimize the work when inside the nested loops. Also, with more info on "do something", it might be possible to vectorize those operations too and gain further performance boost.

Comment: 'do stuff' will just be moving the mouse to the pixel that matches the color of rx, gx, bx.

also, thanks for the suggestion. will try it out :)

Comment: i am getting an error saying 
'mask = (np.abs(im[300:1100, 200:500] - [200,20,20]) <= 5).all(-1)
TypeError: an integer is required'

Comment: @blr69 What's the shape of `im`? Also, can you try with `.all(axis=-1)` instead?

Comment: im = Image.open("photo.jpg").convert('RGB').Load
im is a 1920x1080 photo
but i am trying to check only a specific portion

also ".all(axis=-1)" still gives same error

Comment: no no its rgb. i am trying to find a specific rgb value :|

Comment: @blr69 Do `im = np.array(Image.open("photo.jpg").convert('RGB'))` and then use the codes from this post.